# Necessity of Graviton?

Tags: gravity, mass, higgs

I heard often times that the Higgs-Boson/Higgs-Field is responsible for assigning particles their mass. My question is, if there already exists a particle responsible for mass, why do you need another particle such as the Graviton?

Comment: The graviton relates to gravity.

Comment: @Javier thank you for sharing!